# UiCollectionView and expandable view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have got UiCollectionView with rounded cel (on iPad 3-4, on iPhone 1-2).

I need show view below any clicked cell as on screen (with change text length).

[image]

I spend a lot of time thinking about this.

My first step was make custom cell that show the frame  below cells, but it was wrong step.

Rounded cells changed padding when this was added...

I am using RAReorderableLayout, additionally to swipe cells.

Any idea?

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it a custom `UIView`, which has 3 parts: the part before the tick, the image with the tick and the part after. Then in the delegate method for

```
    - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you can call an update method on this view, that will change the widths of the three parts according to the selected index in the collection view.

You could even send the width of the collection view cell in this update method to use it for calculating the right widths.

Hope this helps! Good luck!